# The meaning of perceive in a context

Tags: word-meaning

The following context is given:

> — When we're asleep, our mind can do almost everything.
>
> — Such as?
>
> — Imagine you're designing a building. You concigously create each
>   aspect. But sometimes it feels like it almost creating itself, if
>   you know what I mean.
>
> — Yeah, like I'm discovering it.
>
> — Genuine
>   inspiration, right?
>
> — Now, in a dream our mind continuosly does this.
>   We create and percieve our world simultaneously.

I know what perceive means but can't bound that meaning to the context. Could you help me?

Comment: I personally don't find anything special about this "perceive", so I'm not quite sure what confuses you. What if I say that it's just the verb of "[perception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perception)", which is about how our brains interpret sensory information? Does that help?

Comment: Perhaps the author is trying to emphasize that  the world we create in our minds when asleep comes from us, but we experience it in dreams as something outside ourselves, other than ourselves, as if it had its own existence apart from us.

Comment: Is this from the movie Inception ?

Comment: "We create and perceive [sense that it is there, feel that it is there] our world simultaneously]."

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase:

> In a dream, our mind continuously does this. We create the dream at the same time as [we become aware of it](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/perceive).

If you're still having trouble with this, perhaps you could try explaining what you think it means?

Answer (score 1):

*Perceive* can mean something like "to be registered upon one's sight, other senses, or mind", describing a passive event.

So typically when you perceive X, X had to exist prior to your perception.

> Now, in a dream our mind continuosly does this. We create and percieve our world simultaneously.

This means that you are perceiving things that did not exist prior to the moment of perception.  Things can "pop in" randomly or unexpectedly.  It sounds weird, but the writer is saying that can happen in dreams.

Answer (score 0):

When we have dream, "we live that dream", except in subconscious our mind knows "this is a dream only", like something we aren't able to do in real life, so at that stage our subconscious mind is creating that dream and we are living at that time and we have a perception for that dream.